# Passing array as parameter in a method

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, chess

I am trying to make a simple Chess program in java. There is an ArrayList that stores all the moves the knight can do, with each move being an `Integer[]`. The first item in the array is the row, and the second is the column. It looks like this:

```
ArrayList<Integer[]> moves = new ArrayList<>();
moves.add({row - 2, col - 1});
moves.add({row - 1, col - 2});
moves.add({row - 2, col + 1});
moves.add({row - 1, col + 2});
moves.add({row + 1, col - 2});
moves.add({row + 2, col - 1});
moves.add({row + 2, col + 1});
moves.add({row + 1, col + 2});
```

For some reason, when I try to run the code, I get around 100 errors including `illegal start of expression`, `<identifier> expected`, and `not a statement`.

I'm not sure what's causing the problem. Does Java not allow storing arrays in ArrayLists, or is there something wrong with the particular syntax?

Comment: you can only use the short initialization of arrays when declaring a variable or field e.g. `int[] test = { 1, 2, 3};` otherwise you must use `new int[] {1, 2, 3}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You always need to initialize the array for this to work.

```
ArrayList<Integer[]> moves = new ArrayList<>();
moves.add(new Integer[]{ 2, 1});
```

Comment: If I used ```int[]``` instead of ```Integer[]```, would I still need to do that?

Comment: Yes you would @ap

Comment: @ap Arrays are objects in Java, event the arrays of primitive types